# Android Studio Custom Shape Button

Tags: android, button

[Custom Button Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpZ67.png)

I want to create a button set like this. I know about rounded corners but i couldn't figure out these shapes and i don't know if it's possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one ImageButton and the image is 3 buttons like you draw and you can control the actions depends where the user clicked on the button

If the user clicked on the button in the 33.3% of the left side of the view, you call its function

Here is an xample:
[image]

```java
  ImageButton imagebutton = findviewbyId(R.id.imagebutton);                       
  ViewTreeObserver vto = imagebutton.getViewTreeObserver(); 
  vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.imagebutton.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int[] posXY = new int[2];
        imagebutton.getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
        x = posXY[0];
        y = posXY[1];
        // Now check with the x and y where the user clicked the ImageButton
        // (print it to see where are the confines of the buttons)
        // now call the specific functions depends where the user clicked 
    } 
});
```